# Are my Hockey skates sharp or dull?

Tags: ice-hockey, ice-skating

I have recently purchased a pair of Bauer Hockey skates and I am not sure if they are dull or sharp.

I looked up a comparison on YouTube, Google, etc. and yet I still have trouble determining if my skates are dull or not.

I am not sure if the blades being shiny have an affect as of if they are sharp or not I just don't know the difference.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE, adding more detail about your skates with link may help in finding answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sharpen your skates after about every 6 hours of ice time. Since you probably don't know when they were last sharpened (if used) or since they don't come sharpened out of the box (if new), you should get them sharpened. Have whoever you get to sharpen your skates show you how to tell if your skates are dull. Easier to demonstrate in person than explain in text.